# Missing return statement error in Java if-then tree

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

I'm trying to tell a Critter program to choose an attack type randomly from four options; I thought I had my return statement bases covered, but I'm getting a "missing return statement" error from drjava:

```
public Attack fight(String opponent) {
   int fightChoice = new Random().nextInt(4); 

   if(fightChoice == 0){
     return Attack.ROAR;
   } if(fightChoice == 1){
     return Attack.POUNCE;
   } if(fightChoice == 2){
     return Attack.SCRATCH;
   } if(fightChoice == 3){
     return Attack.FORFEIT;
   }
 }
```

any idea why that may be?

Comment: This is a good case for using the [switch statement](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/switch/switch-general.html).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the compiler is not smart enough to figure out that you've covered every possibility with the four `if` statements (it doesn't really know about the contract on the return value of `Random.nextInt()`).

You therefore need to add a dummy `return` after the final `if`. It doesn't really matter what you return there, since it's effectively dead code. However, it would be good style to return some sort of unused or clearly invalid value.

**edit**: On second thoughts, rather than return a dummy value, it would be better to unconditionally throw some kind of a "programmer error" exception.

Comment: +1 fro the second thoughts. `throw new Error();` or something more (pointlessly) elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You need a missing statement outside the if statement. For instance, if `flightChoice == 4`, none of the `if` conditions will hold, so you should add a `return` at the end of the method. This return statement has to return something of type `Attack` like the `if` branches.

Answer (score 1):

You might think that your *if statement*'s cover all possible cases but compiler just compiles the code, doesn't cover/calculate possibilities. You need to add `return` statement after the last *if-statement*.

Answer (score 1):

Just think, what happens when none of your `if condition` is `true`? In that case, you would not be returning anything from that method.

You should return from every path your method can follow, else you will get `missing return` statement error.

- You can either make your `if's` an `if-else if` block, and then add
  an `else` at the end, and return some value from there.
- Or, you can simply add a return statement at the end of your method.

Comment: thanks! swapping to an else at the end of the block worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

You need a `return` statement in case no `if` statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

The above/previous answers explain that you need a `return` statement at the end, in case no `if` is true. I would only like to add a suggestion, as a good practice (maybe not best) in this case: just return a result only at the end and assign a value for the returned result in each `if` (maybe add some `else`s to make it more efficient in this case).